# Calculating the maximum of a PDF

Tags: r

I have the following PDF in the form

`f(x) = 3(1-x)^2` for x [0,1]

I would like to calculate the maximum of f(x).

I've done the following:

`integral<-function(x)
{3*x*(1-x)^2
}`

`max(integral(x))`

I can't figure it out where I've gone wrong...

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want.  Do you want the maximum value of the function?  The value of x when the function is a maximum?  The way to get the latter is to differentiate the function and solve for the value of x that makes the first derivative zero.  Integral is wrong.

Comment: Since it's an "empirical" method to find the maximum, the result precision depends on the step you used. This for instance works fine : `max(integral(seq(0,1,by=0.0000001)))`

Comment: Ah thanks - yes that works. So the smaller the step, the great precision? What is the default step on R, out of interest? (Sorry, relatively new to R)

Comment: The maximum of `20x(1-x)^3` is at `x=0.25` The maximum value is `2.109375`

Comment: There's no such thing as default step in R... you wrote that you got `2.057972` but how did you get that ? `max(integral(x))` needs `x` to be defined (as I did using `seq` function)...

Answer (score 2):

The error is due to the numerical approximation. If you reduce the delta you will find your result:

```
max(integral(seq(0,1,by=.1))) # your first answer
max(integral(seq(0,1,by=.0001))) # what you are looking for
```

However, I'd choose an optimisation procedure to converge towards the maximum :

```
optimise(integral, lower=0, upper=1, maximum = TRUE)

$maximum
[1] 0.2499993 # this is the value of x causing f to be at its max

$objective
[1] 2.109375 # this is the max value
```